# Not able to bring aws environment to healthy state in any way . It says-*Environment named is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready*

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, environment

Not able to bring AWS environment to healthy state in any way . It says-*Environment named  is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready*.

I am not able to restart  the application , rebuild environment ,clone environment. On every operation I get the same message. I am STUCK on this.

The issue started with deprecated platform. But it is not allowing to upgrade the platform as well.
Current platform version is 2.11.8 and recommended is 2.11.9. But while changing it also, I get the same state issue.

Comment: What environment? What AWS service are you using and what steps are you performing within that service to get this error?

Comment: Its an elastic beanstalk environment for the java Rest APIs.

Comment: What are your configuration settings for the environment in the config section: Rolling updates and deployments -> Deployment preferences? If possible you want `Ignore health check` = `True` and `Healthy threshold` = `Severe`. These settings are not advised for production applications but might be helpful while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I opened up ec2 in aws console then chose the proper ec2 instance associated with the elb deployment, stopped it then started it. And this solved the issue.